# Toad schema name in objects

Tags: toad, user-preferences

In the Schema Browser, Toad automatically includes the schema name in the name of database objects. For example, when I click on a procedure to see it's source, it goes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_USER.MY_PROCEDURE
```

Is there a way to disable this? Such that it shows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE
```

This would make copying code and running it in other schema's a lot easier!

Answer (score 1):

This is not intuitive at all, but the Schema Browser is using the Editor option to include schema names. See the Editor|Open/Save page in Options. Set the "Owner name" value accordingly in the "Object loading" group box.

Always include - always includes schema name

Never include - never includes schema name

Include on loads from other schemas - includes name when the object is not owned by the logged on schema